# custom view extends LinearLayout can't display in Android N but in Android M is well

Tags: android, android-custom-view

my custom view code:

```
public class IndicatorView extends LinearLayout {
private int[] mColors = new int[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GRAY};

public IndicatorView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    fillParent();
}

private void fillParent() {
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setText("i");
        textView.setBackgroundColor(mColors[i]);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0F));
        this.addView(textView);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int desiredWidth = this.getChildAt(0).getWidth() + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int indicatorViewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int indicatorViewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    switch (widthMode) {
        case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            break;
        case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            indicatorViewWidth = Math.min(desiredWidth, indicatorViewWidth);
            break;
        case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            indicatorViewWidth = desiredWidth;
            break;
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(indicatorViewWidth,indicatorViewHeight);
}
```

}

This is the result in Android M:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6XIC.png)
.This is the result in Android N:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLepg.png)
.The desiredWidth is always 0 see in Log.
I know there are some changes in View's measure method after Android N, but what's wrong in my code & how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
int desiredWidth = this.getChildAt(0).getMeasureWidth() + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
```

the problem can be solved.